# get common elements in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am going to get the intersection of lists for each key.
My dictionaries are:

```py
dict_1 = {101: [['14', '02', '03', '07', '11'], ['04', '12', '05', '06', '08'], ['10', '16', '09', '13', '01']],
          102: [['21', '19', '14', '07', '10'], ['11', '04', '09', '12', '13'], ['03', '02', '15', '08', '17']]
}

dict_2 = {101: [['12', '02', '05', '01', '16'], ['04', '03', '18', '10', '14'], ['10', '11', '08', '07', '13']],
          102: [['21', '19', '11', '07', '15'], ['08', '03', '09', '12', '13'], ['03', '02', '15', '10', '17']]
}
```

What I mean by intersection (for 101):

```
list_1 = Common elements in ['14', '02', '03', '07', '11'] and ['12', '02', '05', '01', '16']
list_2 = Common elements in ['14', '02', '03', '07', '11'] and ['04', '03', '18', '10', '14']
list_3 = Common elements in ['14', '02', '03', '07', '11'] and ['10', '11', '08', '07', '13']
list_4 = Common elements in ['04', '12', '05', '06', '08'] and ['12', '02', '05', '01', '16']
list_5 = Common elements in ['04', '12', '05', '06', '08'] and ['04', '03', '18', '10', '14']
list_6 = Common elements in ['04', '12', '05', '06', '08'] and ['10', '11', '08', '07', '13']
list_7 = Common elements in ['10', '16', '09', '13', '01'] and ['12', '02', '05', '01', '16']
list_8 = Common elements in ['10', '16', '09', '13', '01'] and ['04', '03', '18', '10', '14']
list_9 = Common elements in ['10', '16', '09', '13', '01'] and ['10', '11', '08', '07', '13']
```

Final output should be like this:

```
output = {101: [['02'], ['14', '03'], ['07', '11'], ['12', '05'], ['04'], ['08'], ['16', '01'], ['10'], ['10', '13']], 
          102: [['21', '19', '07'], [], ['10'], ['11'], ['09', '12', '13'], [], ['15'], ['03', '08'], ['03', '02', '15', '17']]
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

I can get all the common elements of two lists but I am not able to do that in nested dictionaries.

Comment: Are the keys always the same in both dictionaries?

Comment: Yes, all the keys always are the same in both dictionaries.

Comment: Does the order of the common keys matter? For example is `['14', '03']` instead of `['03', '14']` acceptable?

Comment: Order of common keys are important and ['14', '03'] is different from ['03', '14']

Comment: Answer updated. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your code is excellent and works properly. These dictionaries are fake data. All elements are different from each other In the main data . I will vote your answer as soon as my reputation reach the 15. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
output = {}
for k1, v1 in dict_1.items():
    v2 = dict_2[k1]
    temp = []
    for sub_list1 in v1:
        for sub_list2 in v2:
            temp.append(list(set(sub_list1).intersection(sub_list2)))
    output[k1] = temp

print(output)
```

Basically you iterate over `dict_1`'s value which is a list itself. For each sublist, you iterate through the sublists of the values of `dict_2`. With `intersection` you can get the common items.

This could be written as a dictionary comprehension if you prefer. Here is the complete code:

```py
dict_1 = {
    101: [["14", "02", "03", "07", "11"],["04", "12", "05", "06", "08"],["10", "16", "09", "13", "01"],],
    102: [["21", "19", "14", "07", "10"], ["11", "04", "09", "12", "13"], ["03", "02", "15", "08", "17"]],
}

dict_2 = {
    101: [["12", "02", "05", "01", "16"],["04", "03", "18", "10", "14"],["10", "11", "08", "07", "13"],],
    102: [["21", "19", "11", "07", "15"],["08", "03", "09", "12", "13"],["03", "02", "15", "10", "17"],],
}

res = {
    k1: [
        list(set(sub_list1).intersection(sub_list2))
        for sub_list1 in v1
        for sub_list2 in dict_2[k1]
    ]
    for k1, v1 in dict_1.items()
}
print(res)
```

**Note**: Since I used set operation to get the common keys, the order of the common keys like `['14', '03']` is not guaranteed. If that's also important to you, you should use another nested loop to check membership testing:

```py
res = {
    k1: [
        [item for item in sub_list1 if item in sub_list2] # <-- Here
        for sub_list1 in v1
        for sub_list2 in dict_2[k1]
        
    ]
    for k1, v1 in dict_1.items()
}
print(res)
```